# ExceptionHandler for WebAPi unit test

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api2, custom-error-handling

I have a GlobalExceptionHandler which handles all the exceptions of a WebAPI in a central way.
I need to add some unit tests to make sure that the exceptions catched by this class generate the Results in the correct format.

In web config, I have this :
 config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new GlobalExceptionHandler()); 
which works perfectly.

I do the same thing when configuring a controller for unit test. 
But when calling the controller methods from unit tests, the exception is not catched by GlobalExceptionHandler. 
What step am I missing ?

Comment: You could deploy locally and have your unit tests make requests to that instead of calling the methods directly.

Comment: We have build servers that run tests continuously. So I can't relay on a local deployment.

Comment: Assuming your build servers have IIS installed, you could.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. so you think there is no way of configuring it in unit test project ?

Comment: You could do your own try/catch in the unit test and build the context yourself inside the catch to pass to the GlobalExceptionHandler. The problem is you are not going through the service but instead just calling the method from a unit test application. That means none of the config logic is hit.